# How to add multiple vk.com like widgets in wordpress loop in a faster way?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, performance, logic

I am adding vk.com like buttons for category archive page. The like button loads fine, and works fine. But the problem is, the page takes more time to load same js files as many times the number of posts I have!

Here is my code :

in my header.php :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  VK.init({apiId: xxxxxxx, onlyWidgets: true});

</script>
```

in my wordpress loop in category.php :

```
<div id="vk_like<?php echo $incre; ?>"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    VK.Widgets.Like("vk_like<?php echo $incre; ?>", {type: "mini", pageUrl: "<?php echo get_permalink($value['id']); ?>"});
</script>
```

Here, the $incre is my index variable, and get_permalink returns the unique page url for the like box.

The problem is, this code loads the following js multiple times.

- http://vk.com/js/al/lite.js?76
- http://vk.com/js/lang3_0.js?3349

and lots more.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

[Socialite.js](http://socialitejs.com/) is your friend. It allows to load social buttons on demand (hover, viewpoint). Vkontakte "like" button is supported but not enabled by default.